# Transforming curl command into Python pycurl or requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, pycurl

Trying to use this curl command, in Python:

```
curl -k -X POST --data "action=login&username=user&password=pass" https://localhost:8443
```

I already tried using pycurl as the following:

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "https://localhost:8443")
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
#tried this too
#c.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, 'user:pass')
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER,"action=login&username=user&password=pass" )
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.perform()
```

I also tried it in requests:

```
import requests


data = 'action=login&username=user&password=pass'

requests.post('https://localhost:8443', data=data)
```

but it didn't work. Don't know what I'm missing, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests


data = {'action': 'login', 'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass'}

requests.post('https://localhost:8443', data=data)
```

Comment: thanks @Danny and @AyushShanker for your answers! I already tried them before and I keep getting `requests.exceptions.SSLError: bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],)` any ideas?

Comment: well you are using https but in your curl request you used the -k option which according to the curl --help: `-k, --insecure      Allow connections to SSL sites without certs (H)` so in that case to 100% simulate your call you have to add `verify=False` (like so: `requests.post('https://localhost:8443', data=data, verify=False)`) to skip the verification of the ssl certificate and not get that error... but then the use of https is kinda pointless.... innit? :)

Comment: Thanks Danny it worked, I used `data = {'action': 'login', 'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass'} requests.post('https://localhost:8443', data=data, verify=False)`

Answer (score 0):

here is requests translation

```
>>> data = 'action=login&username=user&password=pass'
>>> requests.post('https://localhost:8443', data=data)
```